# Image within MaterialCardView does not go to the edge

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

everyone. I would like to display an image within a MaterialCardView. The CardView has a rounded left corner. The image is displayed within the CardView using an ImageView. However, the picture doesn't go to the outer edge of the CardView. It seems like the CardView uses a padding. Here is the code

activity_main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/card_with_on_view"
    style="@style/CustomCardViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/house" />

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomCardViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay_card_custom_corners</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay_card_custom_corners" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">55dp</item>
</style>
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: scaleType="fitxy"

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried. Without success

Comment: make rounded drawable and give elevation of 4dp and remove card view.